# Codesign prompt doesn't pop up

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, codesign

Here's my issue: I've prepared everything as the tutorial said on Apple developer site.

I got two certificates for my app, one of is for developmnet (testing on my iphone) and second for distribution. While first one works excellent, I cannot get the second one to work, here's the problem:

I obtained certificate for distribution, I put it in project info / target info I click the BUILD button and the app builds but never asks to confirm codesigning (the codesign allow/deny prompt doesnt come up).

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong or how to diagnose it? No errors pop up.

Thanks,
Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you clicked "Always Allow" the first time around? Is the built product actually signed?

Comment: Nope, once i try to upload the build to itunesconnect it says it's not signed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not working? I never get prompted to code sign. It all happens automatically.